# xlib - print event name

Tags: c, xlib

So I have a standard window created with xlib that handles events:

```
while (keep_running){
    XNextEvent (display, &event);
    printf("event\n");
}
```

Now it doesn't seem to be calling the expose event, so I'm not able to draw in the window. I can see by the print statement that there are some events being fired, and I'd like to know what events they are.

So basically my question is, how can I get the event name to print it?

I'm still learning C, so any help is appriciated!

Comment: that would all be about xilb, because there aren't any classes in C (as a construct)... printf() also uses a formats string and a list of args, you can "add" (concat with the addition operator) strings together

Comment: @GradyPlayer Ah, thanks, I'll edit the question

Comment: I mean you can _not_ add strings together... commenting from the phone UI is never a good idea :)

Comment: @GradyPlayer oooh, I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I don't totally agree with their design decision, but it was probably made 30 years ago, so now isn't the time for monday morning quarterbacking...

the type is a crazy union:

```
typedef union _XEvent {
    int type;   /* must not be changed */
    XAnyEvent xany;
    XKeyEvent xkey;
    XButtonEvent xbutton;
    XMotionEvent xmotion;
    XCrossingEvent xcrossing;
    XFocusChangeEvent xfocus;
    XExposeEvent xexpose;
    XGraphicsExposeEvent xgraphicsexpose;
    XNoExposeEvent xnoexpose;
    XVisibilityEvent xvisibility;
    XCreateWindowEvent xcreatewindow;
    XDestroyWindowEvent xdestroywindow;
    XUnmapEvent xunmap;
    XMapEvent xmap;
    XMapRequestEvent xmaprequest;
    XReparentEvent xreparent;
    XConfigureEvent xconfigure;
    XGravityEvent xgravity;
    XResizeRequestEvent xresizerequest;
    XConfigureRequestEvent xconfigurerequest;
    XCirculateEvent xcirculate;
    XCirculateRequestEvent xcirculaterequest;
    XPropertyEvent xproperty;
    XSelectionClearEvent xselectionclear;
    XSelectionRequestEvent xselectionrequest;
    XSelectionEvent xselection;
    XColormapEvent xcolormap;
    XClientMessageEvent xclient;
    XMappingEvent xmapping;
    XErrorEvent xerror;
    XKeymapEvent xkeymap;
    long pad[24];
} Event;
```

so you must first use the type to determine which event is being used:

```
if(event.type == KeyPress)
{
    printf("keypress\n");
    // now you know the type you can use the specific fields from `XKeyEvent xkey`...
}
```

or you could just log the type

```
printf("event type = (%d)\n",event.type);
```

the union works because each of the other possible elements also has type as the first element, so they all line up on the same address...

Comment: there may be a function to get the name from the event type int, but I didn't see one offered up by the documentation...

Comment: Just starting up my Virtualbox to try this.. Would you mind pointing me to where this documentation is? I've just been piecing together SO answers and tutorials from random sites because I couldn't find any docs

Comment: Please don't tell me these are the docs http://www.x.org/docs/X11/xlib.pdf if they are, they need an upgrade badly lol