# How can i convert an XEvent to a string?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I am currently getting my feet wet with XLib. In my test program i have the following loop:

```
while (!done) {
    XEvent e;
    XNextEvent(cairo_xlib_surface_get_display(mImpl->surface), &e);

    switch (e.type) {
        case KeyPress:
            done = true;
            break;
        case ClientMessage:
            if (static_cast<Atom>(e.xclient.data.l[0]) == mImpl->deleteEvent) done = true;
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "Uncatched X event: " << e.type << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get a lot of output like `Uncatched X Event: 65`. Is there some way to make this output more readable? I'd like to have something like `Uncatched X event: KeyPress` for example or even something like `Uncatched X event (letter 'e')`.

Is there a way to do this apart from reading the header files and extending my switch directive to every possible event and printing the names manually?

**Edit:** I do not think that this question is a duplicate of [xlib - print event name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590613/xlib-print-event-name) because i am not interested in printing the event in an arbitrary way (i already do that) but specifically in the form of a readable string. I am asking for something analogous to `strerror` but for `XEvent.type` instead of `errno`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xlib - print event name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590613/xlib-print-event-name).

Comment: Fair enough. I thought the duplicate was appropriate because it allows you to print the event's name, which seems to be your goal (`Uncatched X event: KeyPress`).

Comment: I know that I may have to use the brute-force approach (catching every possible event and printing a hardcoded string). I just want to know if there are better ways or somone else already solved that problem.

Comment: [xev](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) had to solve it, and uses a lookup table for the event names IIRC (it does print additional information, again by decoding event-specific data). I don't think there is a generic way to achieve this.

Comment: This comes really close to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *type[37] = {0};
type[2] = "KeyPress";
type[3] = "KeyRelease";
type[4] = "ButtonPress";
type[5] = "ButtonRelease";
type[6] = "MotionNotify";
type[7] = "EnterNotify";
type[8] = "LeaveNotify";
type[9] = "FocusIn";
type[10] = "FocusOut";
type[11] = "KeymapNotify";
type[12] = "Expose";
type[13] = "GraphicsExpose";
type[14] = "NoExpose";
type[15] = "VisibilityNotify";
type[16] = "CreateNotify";
type[17] = "DestroyNotify";
type[18] = "UnmapNotify";
type[19] = "MapNotify";
type[20] = "MapRequest";
type[21] = "ReparentNotify";
type[22] = "ConfigureNotify";
type[23] = "ConfigureRequest";
type[24] = "GravityNotify";
type[25] = "ResizeRequest";
type[26] = "CirculateNotify";
type[27] = "CirculateRequest";
type[28] = "PropertyNotify";
type[29] = "SelectionClear";
type[30] = "SelectionRequest";
type[31] = "SelectionNotify";
type[32] = "ColormapNotify";
type[33] = "ClientMessage";
type[34] = "MappingNotify";
type[35] = "GenericEvent";
type[36] = "LASTEvent";
```

Produced by:

```
cat /usr/include/X11/X.h | perl -e 'local $/;$_=<STDIN>; s/^.*(KeyPress.*LASTEvent\s+\d+).*$/$1/s; s/#define\s+//g; s/(\S+)\s+(\d+)/print "type[$2]=\"$1\";\n"/eg'
```